# How to show live users active on a particular page / routed vue-component, on home page?

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-component, pusher

I am developing an application where users create custom playlists from youtube video urls and those playlist are shown at homepage. When a user click on playlist, it is redirected to a page showing videos in that particular playlist.

Technology stack: Laravel 5.8, Vue, MySql, Pusher

What I have tried so far:

**Home Page Component (PublicPlaylist.vue)** listens to a channel: `live-playlist-playing` on `mounted()` event

```
this.channel = window.Echo.channel(`live-playlist-playing`);
                this.channel.listen("LivePlaylistPlaying", e => {
                    this.object_array.push(e);
                    var array = this.object_array;
                    var seenNames = {};

                    array = array.filter(function(currentObject) {
                        if (currentObject.playlist_id in seenNames) {
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            seenNames[currentObject.playlist_id] = true;
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                    this.distinct_object = array;
                })
```

whenever another user goes to a playlist page e.g. `www.example.com/playlist/1` its component **SinglePlaylist.vue** calls api to fetch details:

```
mounted(){
            window.axios
                .get(
                    "/api/playlist/"+this.playlist_id,
                    {
                        headers: fetchAuthHeaders()
                    }
                )
                .then(response => {
                    this.playlist = response.data.data;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    // if (false == isErrorHandled(error, this)) {
                    //     consoleLog(error);
                    // }
                });
        }
```

Above API method `broadcasts` an event which is listened by the channel `live-playlist-playing`, as follows:

```
public function viewPlaylist($playlistId)
    {
        /**
          some code
         */

        broadcast(new LivePlaylistPlaying(Auth::user()->name, $playlist->playlist_name, $playlistId));

        return response()->api(true, 'Playlist fetched successfully', $playlist);
    }
```

I hope I have tried to disclose as much as details but you are free to ask for more information; coming back to question, Above code works fine for this case, steps to be taken in consideration.

1. suppose a user **A** is on **home page** and
2. now user **B** access the single playlist page
3. **A** will get to know a playlist is being accessed by another user.

But what if user **B** comes first i.e

1. User **B** accesses the single playlist page
2. User **A** comes on home page
3. **A** will not get any information about playlist being played until a user **C** comes in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you could benefit from using [Presence Channels](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/presence-channels):

> This makes it extremely easy to build chat room and "who's online"
>   type functionality to your application. Think chat rooms,
>   collaborators on a document, **people viewing the same web page**,
>   competitors in a game, that kind of thing.

You will need to authorise your connections, then you can subscribe to a presence channel. Presence channels broadcast a member_removed or member_added event whenever someone joins or leaves the channel, which you can use to identify when users are on the page regardless of what order the users join the page.